# shell process not exiting on `exit` inside `$()`

Tags: bash, shell

I have a complicated bash script so I broke it down to the code that matters:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo()
{
    echo test
    # here I do some work and if it fails I want to stop execution
    exit 1
}

echo $(foo)
echo help
```

This is about my script and I would like it to print `test` and then exit but the output is:

```
test
help
```

This is also true for `bash`.

My temporary workaround at the moment is to replace the `exit 1` with `kill $$`.

What do I have to do so it does really exit?

**Update**:

- Just to clarify, only calling `foo` does **not** solve my problem
- Someone suggested this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48533/exit-shell-script-from-a-subshell/48550#48550

  - https://gist.github.com/benaryorg/296386f05b12de599161
- @rici suggested using a temporary file which is not much better than killing the process (at least not in my script), but it is usable

If someone has better suggestions, please speak out!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `kill $$` has the same behavior as `exit` for me.

Comment: @rici sorry that it wasn't clear. I edited it.

Comment: @user000001 I am using GNU bash, version 4.3.39(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exit` builtin command causes the currently executing subshell to terminate. Since the command substitution syntax `$(command)` creates a subshell to execute `command`, the `exit` only terminates that subshell, not the shell which includes the result of the command substitution.

If you really need command substitution, you're not going to be able to trap `exit` from the substituted command. In fact, you cannot even trap failure. About the only option you have is to send the output of the command into a temporary file and then substitute the temporary file in a subsequent step.

In the simple case in the OP, you can just call `foo` directly instead of `echo $(foo)`. But if you needed to capture the output of `foo` in a shell variable, for example, you could do it as follows

```
foo() {
  # ...
  exit
}

foo >/tmp/foo
v=$(</tmp/foo)
```

Comment: So you mean `foo > test;text=$(cat test)`?

Comment: @benaryorg: Yes, I was just adding the example to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to call

```
foo
```

instead of `echo $(foo)`

Answer (score 1):

When you call foo with `$(foo)`, it creates a new **subshell** and that is what's being exited. You need to replace `echo $(foo)` with just `foo`